# Python: Multidimensional dictionary to array

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert a dictionary of the form:

`1: [' Ma','Ant','Man','io']
  2: [' Sc','Alb','Man']
  3: [' Sc','Alb','Sch','bre']`

to a matrix where all the possible values are the columns and keys are indices. 
Each cell of the matrix should contain 1 if the corresponding value ( column header) is present in the key and 0 otherwise.

`' Ma' 'Ant' 'Man' 'io' ' Sc','Alb','Sch','bre'
1:  1    1    1     1     0     0    0      0
2:  0    0    1     0     1     1    0      0
3:  0    0    0     0     1     1    1      1`

I don't know from where to start and how to use pandas and Dataframe to get this done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) to load the dictionary, then use [`pd.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) to get the 0/1 values:

```
d = {1: ['Ma','Ant','Man','io'], 2: ['Sc','Alb','Man'], 3: ['Sc','Alb','Sch','bre']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='').astype(int)
```

The resulting output:

```
   Ma  Sc  Alb  Ant  Man  Sch  bre  io
1   1   0    0    1    1    0    0   1
2   0   1    1    0    1    0    0   0
3   0   1    1    0    0    1    1   0
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!